# vue FormData.entries not provided by submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form-data

I have a little Vue-App with a `form` and only one `<input name"surname">` and `<button type="submit">`.
Use case: input "myname" and submit.

Init `new FormData()` with uploaded form doesn't has entries.

```
// template.html

<form @submit.prevent="handleFormSubmit">
  <input type="text" name="surname" />
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

```
// form.ts
...
import tpl from "./template.html"

export default defineComponent({
  template: tpl,
  ...
  methods: {
    handleFormSubmit(event:SubmitEvent)
    {
      console.log(event.target); // log: <form>...</form>
      console.log(event.target.querySelector('input').value); // log: myname
      const formData = new FormData(event.target);
      console.log([...formData.entries()]) // log: []
    }
  } 
})
```

Why `new FormData(event.target)` does not catch the value of my input?

Comment: It's supposed to work the way you expect. It's not reproducible, please, provide a way to reproduce

Comment: i've found a way, see my answer. Don't no why this works only at this way, but it works...

Comment: I see. You need to enable downleveliteration in typescript config

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is to use `Object.fromEntries(formData)` instead `formData.entries()`